# jQuery (2.0.2) empty() html() Memory Consumption Continually Grows

Tags: jquery, performance, memory, memory-leaks

I've been struggling with this issue for 3 days now and am hoping someone has some tidbit of information which I haven't come across yet to help me out (i'm desperate!).  To provide some context:

Browser: IE9.0.8112.16421 (64 bit); jQuery version: 2.0.2

Essentially what i'm doing is making a simple ajax call and retrieving some information which i'm then inserting into a  element via the success handler.  The relevant lines of code are shown below:

```
var onLoadViewGroupSuccess = function(data) {        
    var target = $("#viewGroupContent");
    //for(var i=0;i<1000;i++) {
        target.empty().html(data);
    //}
}
```

The target corresponds to the following html tag:

```
<tr id="viewGroupContent">...</tr>
```

The commented out for loop above is intended to magnify the issue (which is difficult to detect via single event click triggers).  Essentially when the loop is in place, memory for a single invocation goes from 46MB to ~113MB.

Subsequent calls exhibit the same behavior with memory continually growing.  I initially thought it was an issue with some event handler which I failed to cleanup but ruled this out as I commented out virtually all my javascript logic so the below above is essentially all there is (i.e. no event handlers bound, no custom objects or functions invoked) - i.e. not a closure issue.

Moving the for loop outside the ajax call (so making 1000 ajax calls) results in the same memory profile (so ruled out any obscure ajax memory leaks).  The content i'm inserting is a TD tag containing a significant amount of content (i.e. instances of every HTML tag you can think of including images) so wondering if the content i'm inserting is somehow responsible for the leak.

I've read some interesting blog posts regarding IE's ability to cleanup after itself including the following which seems the most promising (http://com.hemiola.com/2009/11/23/memory-leaks-in-ie8/).  Unfortunately, no solutions or workarounds thus far.

I'm at a loss as i've stripped my app down to the bare bones and not much you can do with `$(...).empty().html(...)`.  The memory leak is slow but persistent....

Also, as an FYI, i've tried non jQuery solutions with innerHTML, DOM methods to remove the table row and rebuild it and then inserting the ajax content into the table cells, moving the discarded content to a garbage bin DIV and then invoking innerHTML, all to no avail, and in many cases making the leak worse...

Comment: Please add some paragraphs, to make this wall of text easier to read.

Comment: @FelixKling Hope that's better...

Comment: What's the use of doing `.empty()` before `.html()`? Isn't `.html()` Changing the entire html emptying the DOM before adding the value?

Comment: the empty i'm pretty sure is redundant, but was desperate as I believe you're right, the html is likely sufficient, but left it in (but have tried both and it doesn't have an impact)

Comment: is this behaviour specific to IE9? Have you tested on other IE? Chrome? Firefox?

Comment: Chrome (v. 27) as always seems to handle it without issue.  The memory does rise above 100MB, but around 150MB it begins reclaiming memory again and never rises much above that number...I should add i've only tested this in those two browser versions (as those are the only two my application is supporting...)

Comment: You should test using minimum data like only one table with one tr/td. See if memory leak still there. Maybe it's a specific element which cause memory leak (image?). Test other jquery version. Try to isolate your issue.

Comment: Update - after trolling through many lines of code, I found one reliable leak source, inserting '<img src="/btms/resources/images/back.png"/>' repeatedly via the html method leaks slowly at about 8MB per 15K iterations, not sure why, but it appears IE is holding onto some data associated with the image....any ideas?

Comment: So think I found the source of the issue.  My application is heavily ajax based.  In fact the only time an actual page navigation occurs is when the user logs out (otherwise what users perceive as different pages are actually dynamically loaded segments of HTML).  It seems IE is only calling a full GC when window.top is unloaded.  The workaround i'm going to employ is simply an occasional page navigation (as opposed to an ajax event) when the record context the user is viewing is changed.  Hopefully memory mgmt. in IE10 is better...(but will leave that to another day...)

Answer (score 0):

See my final comment above, it appears what I was perceiving to be memory leaks were just objects waiting to be GC'd but due to the nature of my application (i.e 99% of navigations accomplished via ajax) IE was simply never performing a full GC until an actual page navigation occurred (i.e. window.top unloaded).  Happened to notice this when logging out and suddenly the memory for my IE instance plummets from 200-63MB...I tried manually invoking a GC (but this doesn't appear to work...).  So for now, going to substitute every nth ajax navigation with an actual page navigation to clean things up...not ideal, but will do for the moment until I can figure out a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the jQuery lib, just to check if there are some improvement about that.

And, remove the "empty()" function. It isn't neccesary, because, html() will override all the chills.
This could help you to avoid memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put the received data into a wrapper element which you remove during the next iteration?

```
var onLoadViewGroupSuccess = function(data) {
    var target = $("#viewGroupContent");
    //for(var i=0;i<1000;i++) {
        target.find('>div').remove();
        target.append($('<div>').html(data));
    //}
}
```

If there is some kind of leak related to the `clean()` API you get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem and solve like this:

[JQuery setInterval with append, increase memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24211034/jquery-setinterval-with-append-increase-memory)

You have to compare if data is the same as the target. If not, insert data, else, do nothing.