# JQuery setInterval with append, increase memory

Tags: jquery, html, memory, memory-leaks, append

Sorry for my bad English.

I've created a chat system with jQuery and when i try to replace contents(like users online-offline or messages recived) it works perfectly but start to be more and more slowly, cause javascript start to take more and more the memory.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
data = '<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>';

$("body").empty().append(data);

setInterval(function(){
    $("body").empty().append(data);
    }, 1000);

}); //document
```

Testing in Google Chrome (I can't post images here cause I'm new). Appears in Timeline Memory more and more, and Nodes(green line) creasing as stairs to, all the time.

I've tested with:

```
document.getElementById("selector_inthiscasetheidofthebody").innerHTML="";
```

and then

```
document.getElementById("selector_inthiscasetheidofthebody").innerHTML=data;
```

- I've used `setTimeout` method insted of `setInterval`
- I've tried with `html()` jQuery method

This is the image:

[image]

Any other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you've got enough detail about your situation.  Looking at this, there are a few problems, but nothing like what you describe.  I tried this, and it doesn't appear to slow down over time, as you describe.

You'll need to post more of your code, I think (if there is more).

Comment: This no slow down cause the example is very simple, but if you see Chrome's timeline(F12, Timeline, Click on Record[Red Button]) memory has problems. If you use it in an application you'll se this more and more slow

Comment: I think it would be premature to optimize if your code is actually that simple, and I don't think the the snippet you posted accounts for your performance issues.  Consider posting more code or deferring your optimization concerns until they become a user experience problem.  The fact that the code uses more memory in chrome isn't important until it causes issues for your users.

Comment: Causes memory in all Browsers, you can cached it with Chrome's Timeline. This is all the code that causes problem. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76885657/stackoverflow/jqueryproblem.jpg  This is Chrome's result

Comment: so, does setting innerHTML directly have the same problem?

Comment: In my browser, Chrome garbage collects this to a fraction once it hits 8mb.  I don't think you have an actual problem in this code.

Comment: But doesn't free memory with empty(). It creases all the time

Comment: And nodes creases too

Comment: Ben West, thank you for your time, i've found it and post it as Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it!
You can't avoid increasing memory and nodes but you can control them!
This is the code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(e) {

// Possible data    
data = '<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>';

// Clean all that browsers changes, like putting styles inline, etc. Data and html appened, must be the same
function clean(a){
    if((a != 'undefined') && (a != null)){
    a = a.replace(/(\ style=".*?")/gi,'').replace(/(<tbody>)/gi,'').replace(/(<\/tbody>)/gi,'').replace(/(\&amp\;)/gi,'&').replace(/(\&lt\;)/gi,'<').replace(/(\&gt\;)/gi,'>').replace(/(\")/gi,"'");
    return a.trim();
    }
    };

// If they are different, then append data. So, you only append data in case information changes.
function inyectar(a,b){
    if(clean($(a).html()) != clean(b)){
        $(a).empty().append(b);
        }
    }

setInterval(function(){
    inyectar("body",data);
        }, 1000);
});
```